# Serving cached version of the site only

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on a local classifieds website and right now every time a page loads the database gets queried.

I have noticed that other popular classifieds websites serve a cached version of their site, which would greatly reduce the load time and server load.

How can I achieve this with Spring Boot or Tomcat? I want the website's cache to update every X minutes.

I am using Thymeleaf as my template engine

Comment: You need to provide more details. Are you using JSP, Thymeleaf,  REST?

Comment: I am using Thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

First you should add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache` to your dependencies in `build.gradle` or `pom.xml`.

Let's say you're using DataService to get data to feed your view. You can put `@Cacheable` annotation on it.

```
@Service
class DataService {

    @Cacheable("cache")
    String compute() {
        return "something"
    }

}
```

Then you should add the following configuration:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {

    public static final String CACHE_NAME = "cache";

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
          ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(CACHE_NAME);
         return cacheManager;
    }

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = CACHE_NAME)
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10* 60 * 1000 ,  initialDelay = 500)
    public void evictCache() {}
}
```

Every 10 minutes cache will be cleared.

Comment: This is one of my services for getting ads https://pastebin.com/zrZYCLNA  but I get the following error when it's executed https://pastebin.com/LXYyfPqZ

Comment: BTW is it possible to store the cache on the hard disk instead of RAM?

Comment: You have to add name of cache in `@Cacheable`. I forgot about that. For you question, you would have to provide `CacheManager` persisting cache. You can ask another question on that.